# How to export/import torrent in transmission in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent, export

I  need to move a couple of torrent transmissions to another idle computer. I have copied all the downloading files into (equivalent) ~/Downloads of machine 2 but the Transmission client on machine 2 fails to recognize the torrent files of machine 1.

So it seems that I need also to export/import other torrent files. Just wondering which and where they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Copy the .torrent files to a staging area.
2. Open the torrent files in  machine 2.
3. Pause the torrent.
4. Move the partially completed torrents from machine 1 where machine 2 has started them - in ubuntu this is `~/.config/transmission/torrents` by default
5. Force recheck or "Verify local data".

[image]

Comment: This post completes your answer for ubuntu (#2) http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1125528

Comment: thanks, I was about to type that in but SI was throwing the error - the location should be " ~/.config/transmission/torrents " . I'd note my steps work with nearly any torret client, not just transmission :)

Comment: I can't find the "force recheck" function in Transmission for Ubuntu... I know uTorrent has this option, but Transmission doesn't seem to. It has verify local data but that only seems to verify the data Transmission thinks it has downloaded...

Comment: Edited answer to fit. I don't have transmission installed, but apparently its called verify local data.